# convertir de binario a entero en python (SyntaxError: invalid token)

Tags: python

```
def aDecimal(numeroBin):
    numeroBin = str(numeroBin)
    decimal = 0
    exp = len (numeroBin) -1
    for i in numeroBin:
        decimal += (int(i) * 2**(exp))
        exp = exp - 1
    return decimal

print(aDecimal(01010))
```

> `SyntaxError: invalid token`

este problema no ocurre cuando por ejemplo escribo print(aDecimal(1010)) osea, cuando empiezo primeramente con el uno.

Comment: El error se da porque para python, no tiene sentido que tengas un numero que empiece con 0, siempre y cuando este no este precedido de un punto (.), si quieres has la prueba en una shell, `01010`, además que en realidad si le quitas el cero del comienzo, el valor sigue siendo igual

Answer (score 1):

No veo la necesidad de crear una función para convertir un número binario a un número entero cuando la función [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)(*python 2.x*) -[`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#int)(*python 3.x*) tiene un segundo argumento llamado ***base*** el cual por defecto es 10 y se le puede poner un 2 para expresar un número binario, ejemplo:

```
print(int('01010'))        # Nos mostrará 01010 como número literal
print(int('01010', 10))    # Nos mostrará 01010 como número literal
print(int('01010', 2))     # Nos mostrará 10 como número literal
```

Puedes probar el ejemplo anterior [aquí](https://repl.it/FqVJ)